# Bootstrap 2.3.2 modal not really a modal (2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-2

There are similar posts to this on SO, but they don't cover the issue I am trying to solve: I am working on 508 compliance, and the issue I have is that while tabbing through the modal, the tab flow does not stay on the modal (i.e. go from the Cancel button back to the first input on the modal). Instead, the tabbing goes to the back ground. I need a way to keep the tabbing on the modal, so the user can not escape with out closing the modal. Also, I am using Bootstrap 2.3.2. Thanks.

Here is the structure of the modal:

```
<div class="modal hide fade x-large" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" >

        <form action="/...">        
            <div class="modal-header">                  
                <h4>Title</h4>
            </div>              
            <div class="modal-body">                                                              
                <div class="containerfluid">                                                                              
                    <div class="row-fluid columnHeaders">
                        <!-- column headers... -->
                    </div>

                    <div id="templateLanding">
                    </div>                                                                           
                </div>                                    
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>        
            </div>          
        </form>           
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide the code where this is happening so people can help you or a js.fiddle

Comment: I'm new to js.fiddle. I'll try to set up an example with bs 2.3.2.

Comment: Check out this similar SO question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183107/modal-with-tabindex-1-gets-focus-on-tab  They have a JQuery solution.

Comment: Ended up being a conflict between bootstrap-datepicker.js and the bootstrap 2.x code. The modal worked fine, until I added a datepicker to it.

Comment: Glad you were able to get it fixed.